# Get week of the month from date in Golang

Tags: datetime, go, time, go-gorm

I want get the current week number of the month from date

I have used isoWeek()

```
func (t Time) ISOWeek() (year, week int)
```

but it's return week number of the year, and also I have used another approach like this

```
now := time.Now()
beginningOfTheMonth := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, time.UTC)
_, thisWeek := now.ISOWeek()
_, beginningWeek := beginningOfTheMonth.ISOWeek()

fmt.Printf(" %d week in the month", (1 + thisWeek - beginningWeek))
```

and it returns "3" when the date is 16 Dec 2022.

Is there any package or solution for this?

Comment: I doubt that the notion of "week of month" is that common that people agreed on how to count the weeks of a month. Just implement how _you_ think weeks should be counted.

Comment: _"and it returns "3" when the date is 16 Dec 2022."_ And that sounds about right. If not, how do you define "week of the month"?